# Rviz: No transform from [my_new_frame] to frame [map] - adding a tf frame to RealSense

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, realsense, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies for lack of images: I'm running this on a computer without screen capture.

I am mounting a RealSense to car, and would like to have a tf defined from the camera to the base of the car. I am also using rtabmap to run SLAM.

I followed the [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28Python%29) to do this, and in both `rostopic echo /tf` and `rqt_tf_tree` I see that my publisher is working correctly. My new frame, [car_tf] is a child of [camera_link] (which is a child of [odom] and then [map])

When I open rviz and add the TF display, I get a status warning - 'No transform from [car_tf] to frame [map]. I figured TF has a tree structure, so the transforms should propagate upward and connect [car_tf] to [map]. Looking at the Tree drop down in the TF display, I notice [car_tf] is nowhere to be found.

On a hunch, I tried to change [car_tf]'s parent to [map]. Everything worked fine. Same with making it's parent [odom].

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324345/rviz:-no-transform-from-%5Bmy_new_frame%5D-to-frame-%5Bmap%5D---adding-a-tf-frame-to-realsense/) by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-31**:
If your camera is mounted fixed to your car, you don't need to write a transform broadcaster yourself. Either use a urdf to describe the tree or use a `static_transform_publisher`.

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2019-05-31**:
the thing is the RealSense already describes a tree, i simply wanted to attach my car_tf to that published tree

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2019-05-31**:
I'll look into `static_transform_publisher` though, thanks for the heads up!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-31**:\

> the thing is the RealSense already describes a tree, i simply wanted to attach my car_tf to that published tree

Yes? I'm not sure how that affects your ability to use `static_transform_publisher` for this.

It just publishes a transform for you, without you having to write a node for it. It'd do the exact same thing as you're doing now yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.. after a reset it turned out to work

---

Originally posted by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) with karma: 71 on 2019-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1